# Como modificar los valores de un archivo Json

Tags: php, json

estoy haciendo un programa de un parqueadero donde a medida que el usuario ingresa, se debe guardar la patente, la hora de ingreso, y su correo, en autos.json ese archivo json se guarda los siguentes items. patente, hora de ingreso, correo, hora de egreso e importe. como el ingreso solo me pide guardar las 3 mencionadas doy por default vacio o 0 en hora de egreso e importe, pero a la hora de retirarse. se le guardara en el mismo archivo, la hora de egreso y el importe. lo cual esas funciones ya las hice, lo que no se es como hacer para modificar los valores por la patente porque no quisiera tener en el archivo guardado 2 veces la misma patente, si no que se guarde en la misma patente y modifique el 0 de importe y la fecha de egreso?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Creo, por lo que entendí, deberías pasar el json a un array con parse y después buscar la patente con algún for o while, y generar el json nuevamente.